# How to open .xls file in kofax RPA 10.4?

Tags: xls, kofax

I have extracted a **.xls**(OLD file format of Excel) file form SAP application and trying to open **.xls**(not .xlsx) file in Kofax RPA 10.4. But it give's me an error. I have added a step and select Action as "load file". Please see screenshot for batter understanding.

**Load file step configuration**
[image]

**Error**
[image]

I think there is no module to open .xls file in Kofax RPA 10.4. Or is it depended on System(OS) Microsoft Office version?

If you know, please share with us. TIA.

Comment: Why tagging "sap"? It's a Kofax topic only, as you could have generated the Excel file directly on your laptop, without using SAP.

Comment: If there have any other option to generate .xlsx from SAP that also be a good solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to add an explanation how you generate the file within SAP software. Note that in softwares like R/3, ECC, the few places where you generate data in XLS format probably all have an option to generate data in XLSX format too.

Comment: I understand your point. I am preparing and will update my question how I generate the .xls file form sap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the output "extract to variable" and create an "open variable" action, select the variable that had assigned from the load file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4IZo.png)